# Conditional update command

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, webforms

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AutoGenerateEditButton="true">
    <Columns>

        <asp:BoundField DataField="Job" HeaderText="Job" SortExpression="Job" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Job_Operation" HeaderText="Job_Operation" SortExpression="Job_Operation" />

        <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status" />

        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />

    </Columns>

</asp:GridView>
```

**The select command returns the following rows:**

```
Job  Job_Operation Status

5294 56250 C 11/29/2016 Edit 

5294 56251 O 12/9/2016 Edit 


            SelectCommand="SELECT [Job],[Job_Operation],[Status], FROM [Job_Operation] WHERE ([Job] = @JobNum)"  


            UpdateCommand="UPDATE Job_Operation set status = @Status where (Job = @Job) and (Job_Operation = @Job_Operation) UPDATE Job_Operation where (Job = @Job) and (Job_Operation = @Job_Operation)

            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:FormParameter FormField="JobNum" Name="JobNum" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I would like to add a condition that prevents the update command from running if the user tries to change the status field from "O" to "C" on any rows if any of the next operations are "C."

Maybe take the select results into an array and loop looking for job_operations greater than the current selection looking for the "status" field with a value of "C"

This is being programmed in C#

Comment: You have one more coma in the select statement after the status and your update command doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Jquery to create an alert if the next row is not complete:

```
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("a").click(function () {
            var row = $(this).closest('tr');
            var index = row.index();
            //this could find the prev value
            var prev = row.prev().find("td:eq(3) span").html();
            if (index == 1) {
                return true;
            } else {
                if (prev.trim() != "C") {
                    alert("The previous operation is NOT COMPLETE");
                    return false
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```